# Building ios app on ubuntu with apple hardware

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ubuntu, flutter

I am Flutter developer and using Ubuntu as primary OS. Is there some chance to fully developing ios app? I know that need macOS and XCode, so I can buy some mac, but I want using Ubuntu as primary instead macOS.

For example my idea is take Mac mini, connect it to my pc with Ubuntu, use some utilities to accessed Xcode services in Ubuntu.

I am using VSCode and I need run ios emulator and build ipa.

Thank for help.

Answer (score 1):

A Virtual Machine with MacOS should do the trick if your computer is powerful enough. I use Windows 10 as a primary OS and I also needed XCode, so a VM helped me.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes I have MacOS in VirtualMachine, but I have some problem with installing xcode components and overall it is not too comfortable as native OS..

Comment: I see. Well, if you have a Mac machine... Have you thought about connecting to it remotely from Ubuntu? I believe that should work too.

Comment: The question is how.

Comment: I have not much experience on Mac, but you could try to search some tutorials about how to do it on youtube, or the easiest way: use [Teamviewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en) since it is available for all OS.

Comment: If you decide to use Teamviewer, make sure that both computers have internet access, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Yes but it is not exactly what I want. TeamViewer is similiar to virtualmachine.. I want run macos in background and using only his services. Just using my IDE on Ubuntu with xcode utilities :)

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible, but I get the idea.. I hope someone else can help you because I do not know how to achieve that. Sorry.